Apache: prime SSL cache or rotatelog?
I found myself in a situation again.
And we know google is in love with pages that load fast.
Since I run a server with apache and Cpanel, I configured it to rotate apache logs every 24 hours (thats the highest setting for cpanel).
Here's where the problem starts:
Apache restarts daily. - Luckily I made a hack in the server to turn that restart to graceful.
After the restart, the SSL cache resets despite using 7-day cache lifetime settings.
I'm using the socache_shmcb_module module that comes with apache to cache the SSL data.
Google may be picking up on this and might be why I may rank lower on https sites.
I also run the logs on a ram drive to add speed to the server but the ram drive size is limited (to about 200MB).
Which means my choices are the following:

Do nothing and let slowdowns occur once per https page per day,
Pipe to rotatelogs program that's shipped with apache,
Copy #1 but attempt to load all external pages from within the server immediately,
Disable log rotation and pray the server doesn't break from lack of free disk space.

If I chose option #2, then how much additional overhead would I face? Because I think executing program functions to write a line is more expensive than simply writing a line to a file.
#3 is tempting as I could force the slowdown to be a minute or so as I re-prime the SSL cache, but I don't know what time of day cpanel tries restarting apache.
What option do you guys think I should use and why?

Why are you restarting Apache daily? It can run for days without needing a restart unless your code has memory leaks or if it is not tweaked correctly.

I store logs on a ram drive that has limited storage space. I could imagine the sad effect when apache tries to log an entry and the storage space becomes full before logrotate has a chance to run.

If you are only reloading due to the logging, I would suggest changing your logrotate configuration to copytruncate These will enable you to avoid restarting the server, and still rotate and release the log space. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47688/how-to-avoid-apache-reload-when-rotating-logs

And if you have limited space, you can configure logrotate not to run daily, but hourly checking on disk usage. It will only rotate if you reach the limit


And we know google is in love with pages that load fast

They say that, IME it it contributes very little to your ranking unless your performance is really bad.

I also run the logs on a ram drive to add speed to the server

Really? That is making your site go faster? Something very wrong with your hosting. And if this is impacting your logs, it will be impacting your content much more.
Now, even if Google happens to be spidering your site at exactly the time you rotate your logs (did you check to see to see how frequently this would occur?) the impact should be 3 RTTs or less.

how much additional overhead would I face?

There should be no performance overhead, OTOH if you had valid reasons for the RAM drive, then your host/hosting does not behave like a normal system.
So, finally I get round to an answer:

I am very dubious any change here will have any impact

There are probably lower hanging fruit elsewhere

If you want to know what impact a change will have, then measure it; there's way too many variables to make accurate predictions

If you are not keeping your log files then why write them in the first place?


